# Why does JS method replace() work incorrect in the latest version of Safari?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, safari

Why does JS method `replace()` work incorrect in the latest version of Safari (11.1) with *"$<"* in the second argument?

Example:

```
"aaaXXXbbb".replace(/XXX/, '_before_$<_after_')
```

Actual result:

```
"aaa$<_after_bbb"
```

Expected result:

```
"aaa_before_$<_after_bbb"
```

PS: "$$" inserts a "$" and solves this problem

Comment: Just tried this in Firefox 60 and it works fine. Inconsistent handling of [replacement patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) between browsers, maybe?

Comment: Its interesting. Somehow the string `$<` cuts everything in front of the replacement so that the following is true: `"a".replace(/a/, 'a$<') === "$<"`. But this happens only using a regex. When you use a string for the search it works fine. Maybe its some Safari internal thing?

Comment: It's maybe worth mentioning that `$<` in a replacement string [**does** have a defined meaning in the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-getsubstitution), but (assuming I'm interpreting the spec correctly) it should only apply when you're using named captures in your Regex. I'd consider [reporting this as a WebKit bug](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/).

Comment: Especially given that @Teemoh's example evaluates to `false` for me in Firefox!

Comment: Yes, in Firefox und Chrome its `false` but in Safari it is `true`. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior doesn't occur in Firefox or Chrome, and I think I understand why.

A new feature has been accepted for inclusion in the next version of the ECMAScript spec called ['Regex Named Capture Groups'](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-named-groups) which, as the name suggests, allows you to assign a name to a capture group in a regular expression. One of the things added by this feature is [a new addition to the replacement string syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-named-groups#replacement-targets) which allows you to interpolate the value of a named capture group.

This syntax takes the form `$<captureName>` - note the `$<` at the beginning!

According to [the latest iteration of the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-getsubstitution), if you haven't closed a `$<` with a corresponding `>`, it should be ignored and just treated as part of the text. The behavior being displayed in your browser doesn't line up with this, and therefore I think it's quite likely that you've discovered a bug!

I'd encoruage you to [report it to WebKit via the process detailed on their website](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/).